# How do I convince postgres to choose the MUCH more efficient of two nearly identical indexes (6 orders of magnitude more efficient)

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization, query-planner

I have some huge postgres tables that seem to be using the wrong index. In a big way. Like, in a 'if I remove one index, the query performance goes up by six orders of magnitude' way. (For those of you counting, that's ~1ms to 32 minutes.) We vacuum and analyze this table daily.

Simplified table for easier parsing:

```
action
-----
id           bigint
org          bigint
created      datetime without time zone
action_time  datetime without time zone
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT min(created) FROM action
WHERE org = 10
AND created > NOW() - INTERVAL '25 hour'
AND action_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour'
```

Two indexes:

```
action (org, action_time, created)
action (org, created, action_time)
```

Let's say an org creates 200k events a day, and has been running for a year. That means that 99.99% of the items in the action table were created more than an hour ago, and action_time is almost always roughly around when they are created, with much less than 0.01% of them more than a few minutes earlier. This means that around 99.99% of rows satisfy the `action_time < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour'` clause.

On the other hand, around 0.3% of rows were created in the last 25 hours, thereby satisfying the `created > NOW() - INTERVAL '25 hour'` clause.

So guess which index it uses?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=55.45..55.46 rows=1 width=8)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.71..55.45 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Only Scan using ix_action_org_action_time_created on action  (cost=0.71..11498144.88 rows=210051 width=8)
                 Index Cond: ((org = 50) AND (action_time IS NOT NULL) AND (action_time < (now() - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (created > (now() - '25:00:00'::interval)))
(5 rows)
```

Yup! It loads the entire index and scans through literally 99.99% of it searching for the 0.3%, rather than loading 0.3% of the other index and then examining it for the matching 99.99% of those records. Of course, if I drop the second index, it immediately starts using the correct one and the performance goes up accordingly.

Postgres doesn't support index hinting, and as far as I can tell none of the workarounds that the postgres dev team says are much better than index hinting would help here in any way. Possibly there is some way to tell it that `created` has a roughly uniform distribution over years (and so does action_time)? Would that even help, given that I can't even imagine how it wouldn't know that already? Is there anything else that could help?

edit: explain verbose:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=57.48..57.49 rows=1 width=8)
   Output: $0
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.72..57.48 rows=1 width=8)
           Output: action.action_time
           ->  Index Only Scan using ix_action_org_action_time_created on public.action  (cost=0.72..11851726.67 rows=208788 width=8)
                 Output: action.action_time
                 Index Cond: ((action.org = 10) AND (action.action_time IS NOT NULL) AND (action.action_time < (now() - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (action.created > (now() - '25:00:00'::interval)) AND (action.created < now()))
(8 rows)
```

I'll add explain (analyze, buffers, verbose) should this ever finish running. Sigh.

edit2: business logic: action_time is ALMOST always before created. 99.999+% of the time. No other requirements, and even that one isn't perfect.

Comment: Maybe you can change the predicate `created > NOW() - INTERVAL '25 hour'` to `created > NOW() - INTERVAL '25 hour' and created < NOW()`; I don't know if the second predicate is equivalent to the first one, but it would decidedly reduce the range.

Comment: Could you show us the different plans using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for this SQL statement?

Comment: And did you try to create some custom statistics for the combination of these columns? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html

Comment: Is your `action_time` always after `created`? Please [edit] your question to describe any business-rule-style constraints on values. An index on a generated (virtual) column may be able to help you.

Comment: Is last element of index ever used ? Maybe in condition like `org= xxx and action_time = yyy and created <zzz )`. So is it helpful or indexes shoud look like `action (org, action_time)
action (org, created)`. Or maybe, considering direction of condition it should be action (org, action_time, created_at desc) or reverted

Comment: @FrankHeikens On statistics: "Currently supported kinds are ndistinct, which enables n-distinct statistics, dependencies, which enables functional dependency statistics, and mcv which enables most-common values lists." I don't see anything in there that would apply to datetimes, which are largely if not entirely unique.

Comment: take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns

Comment: The timestamps might be unique, using custom stats might inform the planner about the relation between the different columns and "force" it to use the better index. This is what you can use as a hint.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I don't understand what you're getting at. Given that we have tens of billions of timestamps in there, I doubt that created is unique. And given that most action_time values are rounded to the second, I know they aren't unique.

Comment: You have an issue with the statistics, that's why the planner comes to the conclusion ix_action_org_action_time_created is the better index. When the database has statistics on a combination (!) of columns, it might get to a different conclusion and picks the other index. Your current statistic assume all WHERE conditions are independent. You have to try it to get it working. Maybe on a smaller subset.

Comment: Why not just drop the 2nd index?  What is it needed for?

Comment: What is the plan that gets used when the 2nd index is not present/not used?

Comment: It is not possible for the plan you show to fulfill the query you show.  I suspect you pasted the wrong query into your question.